# How to write incremental data in ADLS storage from Spark SQL Data Frame Data

Tags: dataframe, pyspark, azure-blob-storage, azure-databricks

we are doing to migrate existing SQL query into pyspark supported spark SQL query, then final spark sql produced dataframe which needs to be write into delta format files in ADLS gen2. we are expecting when we run multiple time the query source table data should be write back to ADLS location with incremental manner. kindly suggest.

we tried as below code to write truncate and load the all the time the data load to ADLS,

```
drop table IF EXISTS tableName;
test = spark.sql(""" select * from datavault.tablename """) 
test..write.format("delta").mode("overwrite").option("overwriteschema","true").option("path",'/mnt/storagelocation/tablename').saveAsTable("tablename")
```

expecting to load full data first time, if execute multiple times, the data should be incremental load to ADLS location.kindly suggest.

Answer (score 0):

For example, I have initial source data like this:

```
emp_id  name    city    country contact_info
1000    Mike    NJ      USA     1234560
```

Next, I have created the `DELTA` table:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE emp_dim(
emp_id INT,
name STRING,
city STRING,
country STRING,
contact_info INT
)
USING DELTA
LOCATION "/FileStore/tables/emp_dim_delta"
```

In order to perform the `MERGE` operation on the `MATCHED` records, I have created the `TEMPVIEW`:

```
df.createOrReplaceTempView("source_view")
```

Then, I have tried the below `MERGE` operation:

```
MERGE INTO emp_dim as target 
USING source_view as source 
 ON target.emp_id = source.emp_id
 WHEN MATCHED 
THEN UPDATE SET
  target.name= source.name,
  target.city = source.city,
  target.country = source.country,
  target.contact_info = source.contact_info
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
INSERT(emp_id,name,city,country,contact_info)VALUES (emp_id,name,city,country,contact_info)
```

After the `MERGE` statement is performed, we can see the `DELTA` table is initially loaded.

```
SELECT * FROM emp_dim
```

```
emp_id  name    city    country contact_info
1000    Mike    NJ      USA     1234560
```

Next, I have `UPDATED` a record and `INSERTED` a record in the source data and performed the `MERGE` statement.

**Results:**

```
emp_id  name        city    country contact_info
2000    corleone    Nevada  USA     78910111
1000    Mike        NYC     USA     1234560
```

Then, you can write to ADLS.
In my example, I am writing the Delta table to the ADLS path like this:

```
file_path ="abfss://folder02@newgenstg.dfs.core.windows.net/ADB_Delta/"
test = spark.sql("""SELECT * FROM emp_dim02""")
test.write.format("delta").mode("overwrite").save(file_path)
```

The below demonstrates an example for incremental loads for Source tables have a timestamp column it will indicate when a record was last updated or inserted.

I have added a TIMESTAMP column to the source table

```
**timestamp_column TIMESTAMP**
```

And then performed the below:

```
df = spark.sql("SELECT * FROM datavault.table_mnw")
latest_timestamp = spark.sql("SELECT MAX(timestamp_column) FROM datavault.table_mnw").collect()[0][0]
if latest_timestamp:
    new_records_df = df.filter(col("timestamp_column") > latest_timestamp)
else:
    new_records_df = df
    file_path = "abfss://folder02@dilipstg.dfs.core.windows.net/ADB_Delta/"
new_records_df.write.format("delta").mode("overwrite").save(file_path)
```

Comment: is it possible to handle when we do write the files to handle this approach? like DF.write \
.format("delta") \
.mode("overwrite") \
.option("overwriteSchema", "True") \
.partitionBy(datefield) \
.saveAsTable(deltatable)

Comment: Yes, partitionBy("datefield") you can partition the data by the datefield.

Comment: my source already datavault table to fetch select statement with business logic to write back to ADLS so that how do we compare each table. we are not create any table to write into delta lake. we just do select operation then that DF to write back into ADLS

Comment: in this scenario, how should we achieve incremental load to ADLS

Comment: again doing try to create table and comparation it will long process

Comment: let me update the solution for you

Comment: When you are performing select operations on DataVault tables(source tables)and then writing the resulting DataFrames back to Azure Data Lake Storage (ADLS) without creating intermediate tables for comparison
You can try incremental loads  Source  tables have a timestamp column it will indicate when a record was last updated or inserted. This column is important for changes that are hapening and to perform incremental loads.

Comment: i am not sure i have around 80+ views to migrate and all the table should be date column is it available or not but i am expecting from you one samples what your explain above those comments, kindly make more understand me

Comment: @Developer KE I have updated the solution please try the updated solution and let me know if you have any queries.